# How to look up previous values in an R data frame by ID and year?

Tags: r

Say I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
  ID Year Value    Value_Prior.Year
 aaa 2010   800               
 bbb 2010  1000               
 ccc 2010   900
 ccc 2010   400      
 aaa 2011   400               
 bbb 2011   300               
 ccc 2011   100
 bbb 2013   100
```

I want to fill in the "Prior Year" column by matching on ID and Year - 1. I would like to do a sum of all other entries that match to ID and year - 1 in case they are not unique. I've created a for loop that will work, but given the size of the actual data I'm trying to find a faster option.

EDIT: There could some years missing and some duplicates. So in above example the last "Value_Prior.Year" should be NA, and the second to last value should be a sum, or 1300.

Thanks!

Comment: Try with `lag` after grouping by 'ID', i.e. `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Value_Prior = lag(Value))`

Comment: Added an edit to clarify, problem with lag solution is that some years could be missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a one-liner using only base R.

```
transform(DF, PriorYearValue = ave(Value, ID, FUN = function(x) c(NA, head(x, -1))))
```

giving:

```
   ID Year Value PriorYearValue
1 aaa 2010   800             NA
2 bbb 2010  1000             NA
3 ccc 2010   900             NA
4 aaa 2011   400            800
5 bbb 2011   300           1000
6 ccc 2011   100            900
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "
  ID Year Value
 aaa 2010   800               
 bbb 2010  1000               
 ccc 2010   900               
 aaa 2011   400               
 bbb 2011   300               
 ccc 2011   100"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

### Update

Regarding the EDIT that was added to the question, complex joins are readily done in SQL so:

```
Lines <-  '
 ID Year Value
 aaa 2010   800               
 bbb 2010  1000               
 ccc 2010   900
 ccc 2010   400      
 aaa 2011   400               
 bbb 2011   300               
 ccc 2011   100
 bbb 2013   100'
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)

library(sqldf)
sqldf("select a.*, sum(b.Value) PrevYearValue
       from DF a 
       left join DF b on a.ID = b.ID and a.Year - 1 = b.Year
       group by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
   ID Year Value PrevYearValue
1 aaa 2010   800            NA
2 bbb 2010  1000            NA
3 ccc 2010   900            NA
4 ccc 2010   400            NA
5 aaa 2011   400           800
6 bbb 2011   300          1000
7 ccc 2011   100          1300
8 bbb 2013   100            NA
```

Comment: Sorry, added an edit to clarify. Some years could be missing and other entries may not be unique, so I need to match on both year and ID and do a sum

Comment: See Update added at end.

Comment: Great - Thank you!