# ratio with a reference value by ID and year using R

Tags: r, panel

I have a panel data with fields - ID, Value, Year, Qtr. I need to compute a ratio field for each ID by dividing the current period value with the starting period value. So, for ID = 1, the ratio would be 10/10, 12/10, and 13/10. Same for ID = 2.

```
ID  Value   Year    Qtr Ratio
1   10  2010    1   1
1   12  2010    2   1.2
1   13  2010    3   1.3
2   15  2012    1   1
2   22  2012    2   1.466666667
2   10  2012    3   0.666666667
2   16  2012    4   1.066666667
```

[Panel Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOTkg.png)

I checked few suggestions such as [How to look up previous values in an R data frame by ID and year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54991610/how-to-look-up-previous-values-in-an-r-data-frame-by-id-and-year) and [Calculating ratios by group with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487526/calculating-ratios-by-group-with-dplyr) - but am unable to code this. Kindly guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the risk of overlooking something obvious, I would use `ave`:

```r
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                 Value = c(10,12,13,15,22,10,16),
                 Year = c(rep(c(2010, 2012), each = 3), 2012),
                 Qtr = c(rep(1:3, 2), 4))

# df$Result = 
with(df, ave(x = Value, ID, FUN = \(x) x / x[[1L]]))
#> [1] 1.0000000 1.2000000 1.3000000 1.0000000 1.4666667 0.6666667 1.0666667
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Disclaimer: Assuming (1) each `Year` (periode) has it's own `ID`; (2) data are in this order. If different, perhaps:

```
with(df, ave(x = Value, Year, FUN = \(x) x / x[which.min(Qtr)]))
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `dplyr` context, you could do this by using `mutate` and indexing on the first value, here using `dplyr::first()` as suggested by @TarJae:

```
df %>% arrange(Year, Qtr) %>%
  mutate(Ratio = Value / first(Value),
         .by = c(ID))

#   ID Value Year Qtr     Ratio
# 1  1    10 2010   1 1.0000000
# 2  1    12 2010   2 1.2000000
# 3  1    13 2010   3 1.3000000
# 4  2    15 2012   1 1.0000000
# 5  2    22 2012   2 1.4666667
# 6  2    10 2012   3 0.6666667
# 7  2    16 2012   4 1.0666667
```

While this works on the sample data, as @Maël states in the comments, a better approach may be to index on `which.min(Qtr)` (for instance, if the names aren't in order):

```
df_scramble <- df[sample(seq_len(nrow(df))),]

df_scramble %>%
  mutate(Ratio = Value / Value[which.min(Qtr)],
         .by = c(ID))

#   ID Value Year Qtr     Ratio
# 4  2    15 2012   1 1.0000000
# 3  1    13 2010   3 1.3000000
# 2  1    12 2010   2 1.2000000
# 7  2    16 2012   4 1.0666667
# 1  1    10 2010   1 1.0000000
# 5  2    22 2012   2 1.4666667
# 6  2    10 2012   3 0.6666667
```

Or in base R using `tapply`:

```
df$Ratio <- unlist(tapply(df$Value, df$ID, \(x) x/x[1]))
```

Data

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                 Value = c(10,12,13,15,22,10,16),
                 Year = c(rep(c(2010, 2012), each = 3), 2012),
                 Qtr = c(rep(1:3, 2), 4))
```

Comment: Maybe indexing on `which.min(Qtr)` would be safer?

Comment: @Maël - very smart! I edited to include this, along with an example of why your approach is better

Comment: `which.min` I think is the best. There is also `first(Value)` and I think you could omit arranging for ID. `df %>% arrange(Year, Qtr) %>%
  mutate(Ratio = Value/first(Value),
         .by = c(ID))`

Comment: Probably, not clear w.r.t. toy data given.

Comment: @TarJae thanks! I edited to include `first()` instead of `[1]` just to keep it all in the `dplyr` family. I initially left off ID in the arrange, though later added it back in just to make the data a bit neater - didnt think about the overhead that may cause in larger datasets